# OLE DB Source SQL changes not showing unless connection rebuilt

Tags: ssis

I have some SQL in a OLE DB Source within a Data Flow Task, that then has a Data Flow Path into a Flat File Destination. Pretty simple process. Run the SQL, output the file to csv.

I have to make some changes to the SQL which changes the output of one of the columns. Changing it from a True/False to a 1/0 output. I make the change in the SQL, but the output doesn't change, still shows True/False.

I copy the exact same SQL out, paste it into a new OLE DB Source within the same Data Flow Task. Connect it to the same Flat File Destination using the same connection in connection manager, and it works correctly and shows me the correct output of 1/0.

Is there a way to "refresh" the OLE DB source so it can pick up the changes so I don't have to recreate every single source I need to change? Any idea why it isn't updating with any changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make changes to a source and the new data type can fit into the old data type and the columns remain the same, then SSIS may not "hear" that column changing (the component does not fire off `ReinitializeMetaData`)

In cases like that, I would

1. Copy the existing query
2. Replace the query with `SELECT 1 AS Garbahfooewoe2ztk;` and click ok
3. after the Data Flow reports errors about previously mapped columns not existing, paste the original query back into the source component and everyone should be happy.

Clearly, if you had a `Garbahfooewoe2ztk` this isn't going to work but the concept is to completely change out the source metadata collection and then swap back with the original.

Comment: Thanks very much (again, you helped me before!) for the help. I knew it would be something simple. Shame it cant seem to see the changes without the little workaround but understandable why. Thanks again!